Cant read Action Payload returned from a RTK Query Fetch using Middleware
Im trying to read a payload from an action that is dispatched with RTKQuery, it is from an async thunk internally that RTK uses. I want to make it global handling using a middleware.
export const ApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'ApiSlice',

  
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: Configuration.getInstance().baseURL, 
      prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        
        const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token;

        if (token) {
          headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        }
        return headers;
      },
    }),


    // Endpoints asignation
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        /**
         * Login endpoint, sends a UserLoginRequest 
         * and receives an AuthResponse
         */
      login: builder.mutation<AuthInterface, UserLoginRequest>({
        query: (credentials) => ({
          url: '/login',
          method: 'POST',
          body: credentials
        }),
      }),

As you can see, here is my login
export const errorHandlingMiddleware: Middleware =

  () => (next) => (action) => {
    

        action.payload.error !! CANT ACCESS BECAUSE UNKNOWN TYPE
        action.payload.status !! CANT ACCESS BECAUSE UNKNOWN TYPE

        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: errorTitle,
          text2: errorStatus,
          visibilityTime: 4000,
          autoHide: true,
         });
    } 
  }
    return next(action)
  }

I tried doing a type guard, it worked, but I dont think its the best possible solution:
export const errorHandlingMiddleware: Middleware =

  () => (next) => (action) => {
    

    if (isRejectedWithValue(action)) {
      
      console.log(action.error.code)

      let errorStatus = '';
      let errorTitle = 'Error';

      if (action.payload) {
        if (typeof action.payload === 'object') {
          if ('status' in action.payload) {
            errorStatus = action.payload.status?.toString() || errorStatus;
            errorTitle = handleErrorStatus(errorStatus);
          }
         }

        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: errorTitle,
          text2: errorStatus,
          visibilityTime: 4000,
          autoHide: true,
         });
    } 
  }
    return next(action)
  }


I tried reading the Documentation, but sadly, it is unupdated and the solution provided there (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling) is quite bad, because its just using the Thunk own serialized error which just shows "Reject" as a message.

Are you trying/wanting to "listen" for any action with error and status payload values, or specifically that login endpoint rejection action? Your code appears to match what's suggested in the documentation I suspect you may want to handle API rejections in your API slice though, either in the specific endpoints via onQueryStarted or in a custom basequery. Can you [edit] to clarify your question?

@DrewReese Im trying to listen to any action with error on all the API section. My code is just like the one in the Documentation, but the one in the docs just prints "Reject" which is the Promise Returned Value. AsyncThunks internally handles errors this way and when rejectWithValue is specified, it does so passing the custom error on the action payload. My problem here its that action.payload is unknown. Dont know if I can make an interface or something to handle this better.
